# Using Python scapy to establish TCP connection, we found a strange problem

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

Environment：CentOS7 / Python 3.6.8 / Scapy 2.4.5
Server IP：192.168.182.128
Client IP: 192.168.182.129
Both firewall and SELinux have been shut down

Server bind port 5000

```
# server bind
ncat -l -v -p 5000

# Server tcpdump
tcpdump -nn port 5000
```

Client code

```
# --*--coding:utf-8--*--
import time
from threading import Thread
import random
from scapy.all import *


server_host = "192.168.182.128"
server_port = 5000

client_host = "192.168.182.129"
client_port = 4000

seq = 88888


syn = IP(src=client_host, dst=server_host) / TCP(
    sport=client_port, dport=server_port, flags="S", seq=seq
)


# send syn
a, b = sr(syn)

# send ack
ack = a[TCP][0].answer.seq + 1

pkt = IP(src=client_host, dst=server_host) / TCP(
    sport=client_port, dport=server_port, flags="A", ack=ack, seq=seq+1
)
send(pkt)
```

server output

```
[root@localhost ~]# ncat -l -v -p 5000
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::5000
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:5000
Ncat: Connection from 192.168.182.129.
Ncat: Connection from 192.168.182.129:4000.

[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -nn port 5000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:12:24.376231 IP 192.168.182.129.4000 > 192.168.182.128.5000: Flags [S], seq 88888, win 8192, length 0
22:12:24.376320 IP 192.168.182.128.5000 > 192.168.182.129.4000: Flags [S.], seq 2649896159, ack 88889, win 29200, options [mss 1460], length 0
22:12:24.384167 IP 192.168.182.129.4000 > 192.168.182.128.5000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 8192, length 0

netstat -atlnpu | grep -w 5000
tcp        0      0 192.168.182.128:5000    192.168.182.129:4000    ESTABLISHED 3409/ncat
```

**However, it is found that no connection has been established on the client**

```
[root@192 ~]# netstat -atlnpu | grep 4000
[root@192 ~]#
```

**What's the problem?**

Comment: You're missing handling of the acknowledgement number. That might be causing the handshake to fail. I'm not sure if scapy handles that automatically, but I handled that manually when I implemented the handshake.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: Read over the [Wikipedia section for the handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment). Note the acknowledgement number. As the client, `3.` is most relevant to you. Unless scapy is handling that (I don't believe it does), not passing the correct number will cause the handshake to fail.

Comment: But I have confirmed that there is no problem with my ACK